# Failing a controller unit test on ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am unit testing an MVC controller. While I can assert the model state after the test has run, I would prefer it if I could make the test fail when the error is being added to the ModelState. My idea was to mock ModelState but it has no setter.

Does anyone know how to listen for `ModelState.AddModelError` in a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a class around your ModelState class:

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{
    private ModelStateDictionary ModelStateDictionary;

    public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        this.ModelStateDictionary = modelStateDictionary;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a validation error to the model state dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key for the field</param>
    /// <param name="errorMessage">The error message</param>
    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        this.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether there are error messages in the model state dictionary
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ModelStateDictionary.IsValid;
        }
    }
}
```

The interface can look like this:

```
public interface IValidationDictionary
{
    void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
    bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

Then within your class, assign the ModelState within the constructor of the controller:

```
public HomeController : IController
{
    private IValidationDictionary validationDictionary;

    public HomeController()
    {
        this.validationDictionary = new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.myService.CallSomething(this.validationDictionary)
    }
}
```

When you pass the instance of `this.validationDictionary` to a service, it will augment the original `ModelState` from your controller.

Comment: This would require that I rewrite a lot of my codebase, which is not an option.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  If you've written it in such a way that you aren't abstracting it out, then I'm not sure whether it's possible... That's why you write the code with testing in mind.  You write your tests first, TDD. :(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. First attempt using:

```
var f = typeof(ViewDataDictionary).GetField("_modelState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetField);
var modelStateDictionary = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ModelStateDictionaryMock>();
f.SetValue(controller.ViewData, modelStateDictionary);
```

with

```
public abstract class ModelStateDictionaryMock : ModelStateDictionary
{
    public abstract int Count { get; }

    public abstract bool IsReadOnly { get; }

    public abstract bool IsValid { get; }

    public abstract ICollection<string> Keys { get; }

    public abstract ICollection<ModelState> Values { get; }

    public abstract ModelState this[string key] { get; set; }

    public abstract void Add(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public abstract void Add(string key, ModelState value);

    public abstract void AddModelError(string key, Exception exception);

    public abstract void AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);

    public abstract void Clear();

    public abstract bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public abstract bool ContainsKey(string key);

    public abstract void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>[] array, int arrayIndex);

    public abstract IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> GetEnumerator();

    public abstract bool IsValidField(string key);

    public abstract void Merge(ModelStateDictionary dictionary);

    public abstract bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public abstract bool Remove(string key);

    public abstract void SetModelValue(string key, ValueProviderResult value);

    public abstract bool TryGetValue(string key, out ModelState value);
}
```

However that didn't work since doing a mock in this way didnt work. So I solved it using Microsoft Fakes instead:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Fakes.ShimModelStateDictionary.AllInstances.AddModelErrorStringString =
    (dictionary, key, errorMessage) =>
    {
        Assert.Fail(errorMessage);
    };
```

Comment: Great to know that you got to the bottom of it.  I'll look into fakes :)